# Why the apache-airflow logs does not show values

Tags: airflow

I am running a simple code to check the logging in from the airflow task. Why can't I see the parameters variable value? I see only the copy of the executed code without the values of the variables

this is the out:

```
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,766] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - import json
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,767] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - logging.info("!!!in test - nb")
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,767] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - logging.info("after json import")
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,767] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - parameters = {}
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,767] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - #/home/airflow/gcs/dags/dependencies/
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,767] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - with open('parameters.json') as json_file:
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,768] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO -   parameters = json.load(json_file)
[2020-05-21 21:25:34,768] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 40: Subtask rna-step1-gsm-srr-task-id [2020-05-21 21:25:34,765] {bash_operator.py:129} INFO - logging.info("parameters is {}".format(parameters))
```

are there any settings that need to be done? is it possible to have the logs in stackdriver?

Thanks,
eilalan

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the BashOperator to execute some Python code, which will not work. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: Please provide more information such as your code, airflow settings.